# How to improve JPA Performance with DB2 backend?

Tags: performance, spring-boot, jpa

I'm currently trying to persist about 200k entities into a DB2 using JPA as fast as possible.
This is used for a mechanism where we read data from an interface and persist the data in our DB2.
If an entity is already there, it should be overridden, if not, it should be inserted.
When using JPAs `EntityManager`, the `merge` operation is extremely slow, usually resulting in a `read timeout`, the `persist` operation however just adds the entities.
I've tried `find` to check if the entity is there and if so `remove` it before using `persist` but was even slower than with `merge`.
Any help is appreciated since I don't even know where to start looking.

Starting out, we just have

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

public void persist(List<T> entities){
  entities.forEach(e -> em.merge(e));
}
```

With Entities like

```
@Entity
public class Town {

  @Id //Id is not generated since it is given by the interface
  private Integer id;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Please include some code. This looks like an once-off migration task and I don't think that JPA is the best choice for such tasks. Having said that, [this guide](https://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html) can really help you start optimizing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out that the main problem was using the wrong AS400-Driver. We used com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver where we should have used com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.
Can't really explain why, but I increased performance a lot.